# Config samba permission in smb.config

Tags: configuration, configuration-files, config, samba, smb

How can I edit file smb.conf to solve this problem:

Every samba user can read and write the folder /myfolder but only the person who created the file in folder can delete his file.

Comment: http://superuser.com/ would probably be a better fit for this question.

Answer (score 0):

I would proceed by setting the (so called) sticky bit on the directory, e.g.

chmod 2755 /path/to/directory

The use of the sticky bit means other users cannot delete or rename files.  More information on the sticky bit is available at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit (or via a Google search).

Thanks,

Patrick